# How to create a Business Objects report which will send a separate file and email for each section but to the same email address?

Tags: report, business-objects

I have been asked by our estates team to create a report in BO (SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.3 Support Pack 3) to send them an email detailing all the information about a case. The have asked for one email per case containing all its details so that they can then portion these out to the team. (each case has multiple rows and columns)

I have created a report which pulls all the information they need and then bursts on the CaseID.

My original plan was to have this run every day, picking up any new CaseID for that day, creating the report and publishing it as a burst with each CaseID creating a separate file and email.

The issue I have run up against is that all the emails are going to the same email address and so the publication just sends one report, rather than one per case ID.

I guess the questions are;

- Is this the best way to achieve this?

  - If not what should I do instead?
- If it is what do i need to do to get send multiple emails to the same address.

Thanks for your help!